# How to program android keyboard shortcuts

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts

How to program android shortcuts for launch program. For example search button + k open my own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your own app, you can listen for un-handled key events via `onKeyDown()` in your activities.

You cannot define a keyboard shortcut that will cause some other application to launch yours.